# Vagrant creates VM, but suddenly destroys it :(

Tags: ruby, vagrant, vagrantfile

I have issues with Vagrant and I wish they disappear. Please help me.
When I installed Vagrant everything worked OK. The problem started when I rebooted
Windows 10.

`CFG:`

```
  config.vm.define "machine" do |machine|
    machine.vm.box = "master"
    machine.vm.hostname = "machine"
    machine.vm.box_check_update = false
    machine.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, host: 2222, disabled: true
    machine.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, host: 2171
```

`LOG2:`

```
==> machine: Booting VM...
==> machine: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    machine: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:22
    machine: SSH username: vagrant
    machine: SSH auth method: private key
==> machine: Forcing shutdown of VM...
==> machine: Destroying VM and associated drives...
/opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.4.0/socket.rb:1198:in `__connect_nonblock': Operation already in progress - connect(2) for 127.0.0.1:22 (Errno::EALREADY)
        from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.4.0/socket.rb:1198:in `connect_nonblock'
        from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.4.0/socket.rb:56:in `connect_internal'
        from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.4.0/socket.rb:137:in `connect'
        from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.4.0/socket.rb:627:in `block in tcp'
```

Answer (score 1):

That solution worked to me when I had the same problem on my Vagrant machines.

The reason is that Hyper-V takes over these ports, to prevent it from happening do the following:

1. `dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V` Disable hyper-v (which will required a couple of restarts)
2. `netsh int ipv4 add excludedportrange protocol=tcp startport=2171 numberofports=1`
   `netsh int ipv4 add excludedportrange protocol=tcp startport=2171 numberofports=1`
   When you finish all the required restarts, reserve the port you want so hyper-v doesn't reserve it back

Optional: You can reactivate your Hyper-V after you've done with the following command:

`dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V /All`

After you done all these steps accordingly the problem suppose to be fixed, to me this stuff really helped.

This [link](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3171#issuecomment-459205576) helped a lot understanding what happened.